# How i can use http.Request more then in one handler?

Tags: go, middleware

I have a basic middlewear it's a Logger function, and when I do `body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)` in each of the next functions http.Request will be empty. But i want that the body contains information. What can I do?

Start:

```
r.HandleFunc("/login", server.Loger(server.GetTokenHandler()).ServeHTTP).Methods("POST")
```

So it's middlewear:

```
func (server Server) Loger(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        server.Log.Info(r.URL, " Methods: ", r.Method, string(body))
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r) //Calls handler h
    })
}
```

And now r.Body will be empty:

```
func (server Server) GetTokenHandler()  http.Handler{
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil{
            http.Error(w, "", 400)
            server.Log.Error(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Print(string(body))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `r.Body` can be only read once. There is no way around it.

If multiple middleware need to access the data, you need to save it a byte slice and pass it to subsequent middlewares.

If the handler had a context, you could have passed the body data as a value in the context.

Another solution, which is a hack, is to store the data in a header field of the ReponseWriter. You should not forget to remove it when returning so that it’s not sent out. Subsequent middleware may then access the data in the header.

```golang
func (server Server) ReadBody(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        w.Header().Add("body", string(body))
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r) //Calls handler h
        w.Header().Del("body")
    })
}
```

Subsequent middleware will get the body data with the instruction `data := w.Header().Get("body")`. Note that a header value is a string, not a byte slice.

Comment: you might also set req.Body with a fresh bytes.Buffer + io.NopCloser in order to not disrupt other involved pieces of code.

Comment: @mh-cbon that would indeed be smarter. I didn’t consider this possibility.